Show φ2φ1 : G → L is an isomorphism
Let G, K and L be groups and φ1 : G → K, φ2 : K → L be isomorphisms. Show
that φ2φ1 : G → L is also an isomorphism defined by
(φ2φ1)(g) = φ2(φ1(g)), ∀g ∈ G.
If I want to show φ is isomorphism, I need to show it is as bijection (one-to-one and onto). I tried to do my proving :
If φ1 and φ2 are bijections, φ2φ1 is also bijection.
i. Show 1-1 
Suppose g1,g2∈ G, 
(φ2φ1)(g1) = (φ2φ1)(g2) 
Show g1 = g2 
Since (φ2φ1)(g1) = (φ2φ1)(g2), it means 
=> φ2(φ1(g1)) = φ2(φ1(g2)) (since φ2 is 1-1) 
=> φ1(g1) = φ1(g2) (since φ1 is 1-1) 
=> g1 = g2 
Hence φ2φ1 is 1-1.
ii. Show onto 
If φ1 and φ2 are onto, then φ2φ1 is onto. 
Let ℓ ∈ L. 
Show ∃g ∈ G st. (φ2φ1)(g) = ℓ 
Since φ2 is onto, ∃k ∈ K st φ2(k) = ℓ 
Since φ1 is onto, ∃g ∈ G st φ1(g) = k 
Hence, 
(φ2φ1)(g) = (φ2(φ1(g)) = (φ2)(k) = ℓ 
∴ φ2φ1 is onto.
Since φ2φ1 is 1-1 and onto, it is isomorphisms.
Am I doing this proving correct? Is there anything else I need to improve or add on?
Edited 1
I added on proving to show it as homorphism.
Show (φ2φ1)(xy) = ((φ2φ1)(x))((φ2φ1)(y)) for ∀g1,g2 ∈ G 
Since φ1 is isomorphisms, it is also homomorphism. 
φ1(g1,g2) = φ1(g1) φ1(g2) 
Let φ1(g1) = x and φ1(g2) = y for reference.
Since φ2 is also isomorphism, it is also homomorphism. 
We have : 
φ2(xy) = φ2(x) φ2(y) 
Hence, 
φ2(φ1(g1g2)) =  φ2 (φ1 (g1) φ1 (g2)) = φ2 (φ1(g1)) φ2 (φ1(g2)
)
Is it enough to show as homomorphism?

this is not enough to prove that $\phi_1\phi_2$ is an isomorphism

It is definitely bijective from what you have proven: that is correct, however , you must also show it is a group homomorphism to prove it to be an isomorphism.

Welcome to math stack exchange. You have to show $\varphi_2 \varphi_1$ is group homomorphism. Another way to show  $\varphi_2 \varphi_1$ is injective is to show $\text{ker}( \varphi_2 \varphi_1 )={0}$.

moreover, the composition of bijective functions is a bijection, so you can use this result and only prove $\phi_2\phi_1$ is a morphism

I see. I already added the proving to show it is homomorphism. Thank you so much for helping!
